# Positioning of Navigation on Website

Tags: html, css

I want to modify the stylesheet on my website so that the navigation remains in the middle, but instead of just 'hanging' from the centre, I want the dark grey to expand all the way to the right and left of it.

I was wondering how i could go about this? So far, the only way I am able to get close to this is by shifting the navigation to the left, and the dark grey background colour goes all the way to the right.

My website is [www.peach-designs.com](http://www.peach-designs.com)

If you wish me to post my stylesheet's here then let me know. Hopefully you can use Web Developer tool for now or Firebug or something.

Hope you can help anyway,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Comment: You are better off posting your CSS and HTML whether or not someone asks. It will be a lot easier to help you if we can see the code without having to go out and find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
width:100%
```

for the wrapper div to make it fill the page width 
and

```
overflow:hidden;
```

for the landscape div 
and

```
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
```

for the nav div to put it in the center of the wrapper div

Answer (score 0):

The banner `div` is wrapped in `div.wrapper` and this has a fixed size. You could either tomake the wrapper `div` have `width:100%` or rearrange things so it does not constrain the navigation.